# Stange removing behavior on observablecollection

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, visual-studio

I am having a strange behavior while trying to remove an element from the Children Collection. As you can see the first time the remove method gets executed the count is 8 (didn't change) but if I step inside the remove method the element gets removed.

What is going on? (hopefully the code included on the images is enough to get a clue about it, if not please ask for more details)

Edit: I already changed a interface a little bit according to a suggestion given in an answer, but the issue remains. this Also lead to some changes on the implementation (mind the red strikes on the image, sorry for the paint skills).

```
public interface ITreeContentItem
{
    string Name { get; set; }
    int Id { get; set; }
    int Level { get; }
    ITreeContentItem Parent { get; set; }
    IEnumerable<ITreeContentItem> Children { get; }
    bool ChangeParent(ITreeContentItem parent);
    Thickness Border { get; }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Please consider adding the [tag:visual-studio] tag, as this problem might be specific to Visual Studio.

Comment: Offtopic, didn't know I would dislike that much seeing a deletion inside a for loop where col.Count is evaluated :) btw, the col Count you are showing is after the item was removed, are you sure that this is not the next iteration you are checking this?

Comment: @Icepickle I am sure because I forced the debugger to go back to execute the remove method. And sorry for that I should save the count on a variable 1st.

Comment: Can you provide the ITreeContentItem code?

Comment: Specifically we need to know what Type children is both in the interface and the object

Comment: @MikeT Included the interface for you

Comment: ok what you Ideally need to do it change the interface to ObservableCollection unless something using the interface will be returning something else in which case ICollection would be better, IEnumerable is only for read only data

Comment: @MikeT It really wouldn't matter that much really because Chlidren property from the interface is not being accesed. It is always the other one since I am implementing the property explicity and I never do a cast to the interface.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

And the problem was very simple... I was incrementing `i` twice on my for loop in the remove method.

Answer (score 0):

Your Children property returns a copy of the collection so you are removing an item from the copy and not from the original collection.

Change your code from

```
get { return new ObservableCollection<ITreeContentItem>(Children); }
```

to

```
get { return Children; }
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, but:
1st. this does not work because the type is different.
2nd. I just tried to return an IEnumerable instead on the interface and didn't work either.

Comment: its the correct reason its not working, now we just need the work around that works for you

Comment: You are welcome. You might want to read about covariance/contravariance to see why this design (manipulating a Collection<T> through a Collection<BaseT>) was a bad idea.

Comment: @Guillaume Yeah the decision of returning a ObservableCollection on the interface was a bad one. I changed to IEnumerable and I can now return just Children without any worries.